# Slick Plain SQL Queries Get Count

Tags: sql, scala, slick

Using a **Plain SQL Query** in Slick I want to do a query and get back the row count, I don't care about the data.

Should I use updateNA?  Calling execute on StaticQuery returns nothing.  How do I get the row count?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.first` instead or `.execute`. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/api/index.html#scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery0

And if you have a normal select (rather than a delete or update), you need to ask for the row count as Dan suggested.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to modify the SQL query you're executing to return the row count, by surrounding it with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...)`. This is easiest if you have the raw SQL string to work with, but it can also be done if you have a `StaticQuery` object:

```scala
def getRowCount[P](q: StaticQuery[P, _], params: P = ())
               (implicit pconv: SetParameter[P], rconv: GetResult[Int]): Int = {
  val q2 = StaticQuery.query[P, Int](
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (" + q(params).getStatement + ")")
  q2(params).first
}
```